# Text next to Image vs. stacked on mobile

Tags: css, image, text, responsive, stacked

I'm having trouble with making the text and image be responsive on mobile.

This is what I have
HTML:

```
<div class="split-content" style="width:50%; background-color: #ffffff; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FAFAFA, #ffffff ); height: 212.5;max-width: 300px; display: inline-block;float:left">
```

Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
Sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem commodi.

And CSS:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  body {
    font-family: 'Lato', San serif;
    Font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  }
  .headers {
    Font-weight: 700 !important;
  }
  .heads {
  letter-spacing: 3px !important;
  Font-weight: 700 !important;
  }
  .blog {
  letter-spacing: 0.6px !important;
  Font-weight: 400 !important;
  }
</style>
```

I want these images to show on top of their text on mobile
[image]

Can someone please help me, please?

Comment: can you be more specific with your code and try to add some jsfiddle so that anyone can change the code easily

Comment: I'm trying to design an email in MailChimp, by having my own HTML. So I added a code for CSS and another for HTML. I posted my codes here, and that's all I know :( I'm a beginner.

Comment: @MaherSinjary i have posted answer to your query. let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

i have an answer, you can use float values for this kind of approach and make float none in mobile resolution using media query , it would be same as you like to view image on top and them text for mobile resolution. Kindly check the example.

Code

```css
.break {
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}
.right{ 
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
.left{ 
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
@media (max-width:767px){ .left, .right { float:none;}}
```

```html
<div class="split-content" style="">
    <div class="right"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/></div>
    <div class="left">testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest</div>
    
    <div class="break"></div>
    
    <div class="left"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/></div>
    <div class="right">testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest</div>
    
    <div class="break"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Anmol - thanks but I treid your code, it's not responsive!

Comment: You have to use media queries for that for e.g @media(max-width:767px){.left, .right {float:none;}}. 

Check and let me know, it will definately work out for you

Comment: I have updated that with the media query , you can check

Comment: @MaherSinjary, it is working now , i have added a media query in the snippet

Comment: I'm really very new to coding, I tried to add this media queries to my CSS and still it doesn't affect it. 
May I ask where I should place the 2nd code? which starts with 

<div class="split-content" style="">
    <div class="right"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/></div>
    <div class="left">testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest</div>

Comment: have you added viewport to your html?

Comment: You need to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your html in head tag to make it work. Please add and let me know :-)

Comment: So as I said I'm doing this for an email, so the HTML that I have actually doesn't start with <html> in the code, it starts with <div class="split-content" style="" 

In this case, where should I add that <meta code?

Comment: Email templates also include html and  head tag, as titles are always defined there.

Comment: Is there a way I can send you my code and you can edit it?

Comment: email me anmolsandal@gmail.com. let me know when sent

Comment: I just emailed you the HTML and CSS codes. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Haven't received yet

Comment: I'll forward it again, meanwhile, please also check your spam folder.

Comment: You nedd to keep style in head tag, that is the mistake i will reply you in the same email

Comment: I updated the style, but you saw my HTML too, what should I change in there in order for it to work? Because now I'm still having the same issue :(

Comment: You only need to update the section that i have sent , keep html as it is

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i have used in my website for similar situation 
 If you use flex-box display for content alignment and wrapping then you can add `CSS` `order` property to specify the order of elements in alignment i have modified the previous answer code with that property have a look

 Drop a comment if you dont understand any line...

```css
.content{
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  height: 200px;
}
@media (max-width:760px){
   .second{ order:1;}
  .first{ order:2;}
  .content{
    width: 90%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="split-content" >
  <div style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
   <div class="content first">testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest</div>
    <div class="content second"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/></div></div>
    <div class="content"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/></div>
    <div class="content">testtesttesttesttest</div> 
    <div></div>
 </div>
```

Here is the codepen link you can view and edit that to clarify my procedure https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZqEoy?editors=1100 
 Pardon me by any chance codepen doesnt work 
As you said you are beginner then go through the flex box display properties you can make you website wire-frame alignment perfectly as you want with flex box display. Thank You...

Comment: Hi Aravind - actually I tried your code it didn't work either :(
This is for a MailChimp email, not for a website. Is that CSS the same for email and web page?

Comment: I dont think so this works only with CSS3 i'll do some research and let you know.. Thank you